# How to Overcome Conflicts in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In form, I want the function to take data from form one to another form automatically and automatic calculations run together. but here only one function can be run.

[in my foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAMYb.png) I want when I select LAO, it will automatically retrieve data from other forms and appear in the Posisi Awal textfield. then when I fill the Persen textfield, then automatically calculates and fills in the data from the calculation of the Posisi Awal with Persen in the Target Awal textfield. The problem is the automatic calculation works but retrieving data from the form to another form does not work.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'posisi_awal')->textInput(['id'=>'posisi_awal','onkeyup'=>'sum();','type' => 'number','maxlength' => true])->label('Posisi Awal') ?>
```

when I omit 'id' => 'posisi_awal' in this code. for the function of retrieving data from another location it can run, but for automatic calculations it cannot

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Resumes;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Monitoring */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
$model->tgl = date('Y-m-d');
?>

<script>
function sum() {
      var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('posisi_awal').value;
      var txtFourNumberValue = document.getElementById('persen').value;

      var result1 = parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue) / 100 * parseInt(txtFourNumberValue);

      var hasil1 = Math.ceil(result1);

      if (!isNaN(hasil1)) {
         document.getElementById('target_awal').value = hasil1;
      } 

}
</script>

<div class="monitoring-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'kode_lao')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Resumes::find()->all(),'resumes_id',function($model){return ($model->lao.' ('.$model->tgl.')');}),
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih LAO (Tanggal)','required' => true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true,'id'=>'lao'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tgl')->textInput(['readOnly'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'posisi_awal')->textInput(['id'=>'posisi_awal','onkeyup'=>'sum();','type' => 'number','maxlength' => true])->label('Posisi Awal') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'persen')->textInput(['id'=>'persen','onkeyup'=>'sum();','type' => 'number','maxlength' => true])->label('Persen') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'target_awal')->textInput(['id'=>'target_awal','onkeyup'=>'sum();','type' => 'number','maxlength' => true])->label('Target Awal') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<?php
$script = <<< JS

$('#lao').change(function(){
    var laoId = $(this).val();

    $.get('index.php?r=resumes/get-persen-eom',{ laoId : laoId },function(data){
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);

        $('#monitoring-tgl').attr('value',data.tgl);
        $('#monitoring-posisi_awal').attr('value',data.tgt_pergeseran);

    });
});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you provide your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: why does the textfield Posisi Awal not automatically fill when Kode Lao is selected?@sony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('#monitoring-tgl').attr('value',data.tgl);
    $('#monitoring-posisi_awal').attr('value',data.tgt_pergeseran);
```

You don't have fields with those ID's on that page.

Also if you change some input value then you need to trigget a `change` event on that input for other code that is reliant on that fields `onchange` event to trigger.

Why are you changing value of an input using attr? jQuery has `.val(value)` method for this: http://api.jquery.com/val/

So correct usage would be something like this:

```
    $('#monitoring-tgl').val(data.tgl).trigger("change");
    $('#monitoring-posisi_awal').val(data.tgt_pergeseran).trigger("change");
```

Or maybe even like this. As I think you are refering to the `#posisi_awal` input there actually. But I dont have a clue about `#monitoring-tgl` input. Does not seem to exist on that page.

```
    $('#monitoring-tgl').val(data.tgl).trigger("change");
    $('#posisi_awal').val(data.tgt_pergeseran).trigger("change");
```

Comment: it's work, in the second answer. Thank you very much thank you very much